# wikipedia api - relative urls | remove or redirect links

Tags: angularjs, wikipedia-api

Currently I've been using the following request to display the Wikipedia content on my AngularJS app:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&page=little%20tinamou
```

Using the following, I display all the text on the page:

```
var lowercaseBirdname = $filter('lowercase')($scope.birdname);
console.log(lowercaseBirdname);
birdApi.getWikipedia(lowercaseBirdname)
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res.data.parse.text['*']);
        var toHtml = res.data.parse.text['*'];
        document.getElementById("extract").innerHTML = toHtml;
    });
```

All the images, external links are showing, though in the html you can see that the page has alot of `'/wiki/'` links which redirects me to my own url.

How do I bypass this, do give a redirect to the wikipage on a new tab, or can I simply remove all the links while keeping the layout/images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the html using `angular.element()` and adjust the `href` of resultant dom nodes then return to string before passing to the view:

```
 var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&page=little%20tinamou',
  wikiBaseUrl = "http://en.wikipedia.org";
  $http.jsonp(url).then(function(resp){
     var html = resp.data.parse.text['*'];
     // create a div and append html data
     var div = angular.element('<div>').append(html),
     // create collection of the `<a>` elements 
     links = div.find('a');
     // loop over `<a>` elements and adjust href
     for(var i =0; i<links.length; i++ ){
       var el = links[i];
       var $link =angular.element(el) , href = $link.attr('href');
       if(href[0] ==='/'){
         // set absolute URL.
         $link.attr('href', wikiBaseUrl + href)
       }
     }
     // return the modified html string from the div element
     $scope.html = div.html();

  });
```

Note that many of the href are hashes for in-page ID. Not sure what you want to do with those

Should use `ng-bind-html` along with `ngSanitze` and not do any dom manipulation in controllers

```
<div ng-bind-html="html">
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/T3E67bz1sbfEIcR7V3aT?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Yea I also so that (concirning the hashes). I'm thinking of maybe simply hiding those through the css? Or is there a way to counter it and simply remove those.

Comment: You could open in live wikepedia page by parsing the page url from the data and check if url starts with `#`. Not sure how you want those to work since the matching ID's don't seem to be avaialble in response

Comment: When looking at the console, I see that all these links are refrences. Therefor have the tag: ´class="refrence"´. I'm leaning more towards the solution of simply doing ´display:none´ for that class..

Comment: Also note other solution is not sanitizing the data which ng-bind-html will do for you.

Comment: that is true, i'll give ngSanitize a look. Don't really know it yet. Will keep you posted

Comment: On a side note, can the links be opened in a new tab somehow?

Comment: Sure...just also set `attr('target','_blank')`. Will seem counter-intuitive to user but will work

Comment: Well this seems to work and it clears out the html that is unnecessary. Seems to do the trick. On a side note: I have been struggling with something else concirning my project. (Mind if we take this to a chat?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114429/discussion-between-borni-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 1):

Since angular has embedded jquery functionality as `angular.element`, you can do and wrap all the html manipulation in a custom directive.

This directive will get the html string from wikipedia api response, load them into an element, lookup and replace for relative urls and with wikipedia base url and will store the result on the directive's element.

#### Online demo - https://plnkr.co/edit/0wtFVOhxw0NfRw43x8K6?p=preview

html:

```
<button ng-click="reload()">Reload</button>
<hr>
<div wikipedia-content="getWikipediaContent()"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

var WIKIPEDIA_BASE_URL = 'http://en.wikipedia.org';

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.reload = function() {

    // hard coded for testing purposes
    $scope.response = {
      "parse": {
        "title": "Little tinamou",
        "pageid": 805527,
        "revid": 697345219,
        "text": {
          "*": "<div>\n<table cl ... "
        }
      }
    };
  };

  $scope.getWikipediaContent = function getWikipediaContent() {

    if (!$scope.response) {
      return '';
    }

    return $scope.response.parse.text['*']
  };

});

app.directive("wikipediaContent", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      wikipediaContent: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, directiveElement) {


      scope.$watch('wikipediaContent', function() {

        if (!scope.wikipediaContent) {
          return;
        }

        var wikipediaElement = angular.element(scope.wikipediaContent);
        wikipediaElement.find('a').each(function() {

          var element = angular.element(this);
          var href = element.attr('href');

          if (href.match(/^http/)) {
            return;
          }

          element.attr('href', WIKIPEDIA_BASE_URL + href);
        });


        directiveElement.replaceWith(wikipediaElement);

      });
    }
  }
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/0wtFVOhxw0NfRw43x8K6?p=preview

Comment: Though what I am retrieving is a whole layout. This will not display it on the page. Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: didn't understand your comment. do you want taking this to the chat?

Comment: I want to display the text given through the api.
If you check the link up above, the sponse is a full html layout when resolving `res.data.parse.text['*']` using what you suggested above with not give me this result. Hence me not understanding your answer.

Comment: let's chat, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114422/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-37764415

Comment: Since solution requires jquery ... cleaner to use `$()` instead of writing out `angular.element()`. With exception of `each` though no need for jQuery in your solution

Comment: Also will end up with wrong url for all the hashed in-page href's - see Contents section for example

Comment: @charlietfl so you are saying this is wrong? because I have just tried it, and it works using the directive (with a bit of tweaks)

Comment: @JossefHarush Is there a way to open the links in a blank tab using this code?

Comment: @Borni what I'm saying is there are lots of href that are like `#PageId` so those would end up going to wikipedia home page if only check for `http`. Need to also check for those before modifiying

Answer (score -2):

Replace all the relative urls with absoluteUrls,

example: replace `/wiki/File:Crypturellus_soui.jpg` with `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Crypturellus_soui.jpg`

NOTE: This should open the image in wikipedia page in current browser tab.

Comment: How can I replace all the urls, if the result displayed through a json.
I am calling random pages and displaying them.

Comment: + the images are working since the response displays the urls in the json. Hence that not being the issue